# How do you get an average of a sum of numbers whose scope is dependent on a row and column group

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008, calculated-columns

I'm a bit of a noobie working with SSRS 2008 and I'm having trouble trying to get the average of a sum of numbers. Here is how my report looks like (I couldn't put in a screen shot, hopefully the text table I created makes sense ):

Example |

```
ParentCode | ChildCode | Total Grade | A | B | A%    | B%
```

P1

```
             1234       5             1   4   20%     80%

               Totals   5             1   4   20%     80%
```

P2

```
             4567       6             3   3   50%     50% 

             5555       3             2   1   66.7%   33.3%

               Totals   9             5   4   58.35%  41.65%
```

I am calculating the percentage of grades for each ChildCode (ie. code 5555 has 2 A's out of 3 grades total, so its A% = 66.67%). I am doing this by using scope descriptors:

=sum(Fields!grade.Value)/sum(Fields!grade.Value,"gradePercCol")

Where the first sum's scope is by the row grouping (ChildCode) and the second sum is by the grade percent column grouping.

For whatever reason, I need to get the average of these percentages. Ie:

For parent code P2, I need the average for column A%: (50% + 66.67%) / 2 = 58.35, as well as for the B% column and so on. The "Totals row" in my example would be an example of what I need.

I think I need to make a custom aggregate since the original percentages are calculated using the sum function and I can't get an average of an aggregate function. However, I'm having a lot of trouble understnding the documentation for custom aggregates.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934256(v=sql.100).aspx

Any help clarifying these links or pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your clients realize that they are averaging averages?

I think the best solution would be to derive your grade percentage in your data set.  If you can do that, then you can just do a avg(percentage) in your group footer.

Comment: Yes, i ended up rewriting my query to do most of the math instead of trying to do it within the report.

I have no idea why this was apart of the original report, and the person that reviewed my converted reports also had the same question. But its there for their viewing pleasure.

Thank you so much for answering, I'm very sorry I didn't respond right away.